# How to show loader for Jquery UI autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am not able to show a loader image for jquery autocomplete. I have gone through most of the links available in web. But none works perfectly.
Most says adding this css will resolve the issue. But does not work for my case.

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading { 
  background:url('http://localhost/tt/loading.jpg') no-repeat right center 
}
```

Please help.Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  $("#tags").autocomplete({

    source: availableTags
  });



});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: url('http://s28.postimg.org/ovve48q21/ajax_loader.gif') no-repeat right center
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder if select2 would be a good solution for you: https://select2.github.io/

Comment: That's not an AJAX source... You will probably notice significant lag loading the page if your array is large enough to require a loading image.

Comment: @doveyg: No, It does not work with ajax also. My original app uses ajax.